# Mocking an object with hidden constructor with method present in superclass definition

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a peculiar case where I have to mock a method call from a class which is written in its super class definition.

The constructor of the subclass is not visible and so is for the superclass preventing to create a spy mock of them. Now when the clause runs during test it throws `NullPointerExcepetion` as it is not able to find the method in its mocked object. How to write powermockito or mockito code for this code:

```
@Mock
QualifiedBuilder qualifiedBuilder;    
//test code follows
 Mockito.when(qualifiedBuilder.newClient()).thenReturn(realTimeNotificationServiceClient);
```

New client method is not directly exposed or over written in "QualifiedBuilder" class definition rather comes from is superclass definition

Comment: I assume that you are in socpe of testing `QualifiedBuilder`. IMHO it is bad place to test method of superclasss in test context of extending class. Why dont you test superclass in separate case and use package access to get to hidden elements?

Comment: I have to test some other class actually where the qualifiedBuilder.newClient() is being called. The call needs to be mocked.

Comment: The only way will be to make test class actually "testable". This can be done by adding additional partially visible constructor that can accept `qualifiedBuilder` as a parameter. You will be able to provide mock there. Another way would be to make some internal methods protected, extend and override those internals to suit test needs or make them package protected so the test case class from the same package will be able to modify internals.The last resort would be to use `Reflection` to access private members and modifiy them directly.